# how to retrieve limited number of IPs when Consul service catalog is queried

Tags: consul, consul-template

Is there a way to retrieve only 3 IPs from Consul service catalog?

```
{{if service 'web' 'passing'}}
 "{{range $index, $service := service 'web'}}{{if ne $index 0}},{{end}}{{.Address}}{{end}}"
```

The above code gets all comma separated IPs (I have 100's of IPs) that passes the web service check . I just need first 3 IPs.

-W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{range $index, $service := service "web"}}{{if gt $index 3}}{{.Address}}:{{ .Port }},{{end}}{{end}}`

should do it.